# How to access the subtags within a tag using beautifulsoup in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to retrieve player statistics from MLB.com for the 2016 season. I am using Beautiful Soup in Python, and I need to extract the information in the table seen here:

[http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type='R'&season=2016&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1493672037085&playerType=ALL&sportCode='mlb'&split=&team_id=&active_sw=&position=&page_type=SortablePlayer&sortOrder='desc'&sortColumn=ab&results=&perPage=442&timeframe=&last_x_days=&extended=0](http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+hitting&game_type=%27R%27&season=2016&season_type=ANY&league_code=%27MLB%27&sectionType=sp&statType=hitting&page=1&ts=1493672037085&playerType=ALL&sportCode=%27mlb%27&split=&team_id=&active_sw=&position=&page_type=SortablePlayer&sortOrder=%27desc%27&sortColumn=ab&results=&perPage=442&timeframe=&last_x_days=&extended=0)

Here is what I have attempted:

```
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
gdata=soup.find_all('div',{'id':'datagrid'})
print(gdata)
```

This should return all of the subtags within the tag, but it does not. This results in the following:

```
[<div id="datagrid"></div>]
```

Can anyone explain why this is not producing the contents of the table? Furthermore, what can I do to access the contents of the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for the webpage, it looks like the `datagrid` div is actually empty & the stats are inserted dynamically as json from [this URL](http://mlb.mlb.com/pubajax/wf/flow/stats.splayer?season=2016&sort_order=%27desc%27&sort_column=%27ab%27&stat_type=hitting&page_type=SortablePlayer&game_type=%27R%27&player_pool=ALL&season_type=ANY&sport_code=%27mlb%27&results=1000&recSP=1&recPP=442).  Maybe you can use that instead.  To figure this out I looked at the page source to see that the div had no children and then used Chrome developer tools Network tab to find the request where it pulled the data:

1. Open the web page
2. Open the chrome developer tools, Command+Option+I (Mac) or Control+Shift+I (Windows, Linux).
3. Refresh the web page with the tools open so it processes the network requests then wait for the page to load
4. (optional) Type `xml` in the search bar on the web to narrow your search results to requests that are likely to have data
5. Click on each request and look at the preview of the response.  At this point I just manually examined the responses to see which had your data.  I got lucky and got yours on the first try since it has stats in the name.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can and will use that URL for my data. I will also need to find more data from the same place (different stats). Can you explain in further detail how you determined what URL the datagrid was getting its information from?

Comment: So I think I found the correct request (for this example I am working on, it was entitled "bam.xml.js") since it was requested as the table loaded and is an xml file. However, I still don't see any URL's within the request response. Can you take a screenshot of where the URL would be in the request?

Comment: Under the "Headers" tab, in "General" (the first section), you should see "Request URL" as the first item.  You can also double click on the request from the list and that will open it in a new tab where you can copy the URL

Comment: I got the link (http://mlb.mlb.com/shared/scripts/bam/bam.xml.js), but it led me to the response page, not the statistics from the first example. Do I have the wrong request?

Comment: [link](http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable.jsp#elem=%5Bobject+Object%5D&tab_level=child&click_text=Sortable+Player+fielding&game_type='R'&season=2016&season_type=ANY&league_code='MLB'&sectionType=sp&statType=fielding&page=1&ts=1493698214609&playerType=ALL&sportCode='mlb'&split=&team_id=&active_sw=&position=&page_type=SortablePlayer&sortOrder='desc'&sortColumn=inn&results=&perPage=442&timeframe=&last_x_days=&extended=0). Here is the page I am trying to get if you wanted to take a look

Comment: Nevermind, I did indeed have the wrong request. The correct request ended up being "stats.splayer?season=2016&..." Thanks so much!